# PD Read in Jupyter Notebook 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I began a simple project and I cannot get pandas in my Jupyter notebook to read my file as I get an attribute error message:

```
import pandas as pd  
bank_churn = pd.read.csv('CustomerChurn')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-38cc87a5bfa3> in <module>
----> 1 bank_churn = pd.read.csv('CustomerChurn')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    212 
    213             return Panel
--> 214         raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
    215 
    216 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv` I think.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use

```
pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Comment: That worked!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I try the ways in which I have been taught online then a newer way comes in with the latest versions...so irritating as this is one of MANY!